# Javascript not working when loading element from separate HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using

```
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
    integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script> 
    $(function(){
    $("#header").load("header.html"); 
    });
</script>
```

to load my sidebar navigation into my HTML file and everything works fine and looks the same, except buttons that use JS doesn't do anything when importing it from a separate HTML document. Anyone got any ideas what I might have missed?

Here's the element I'm loading:

```
<header class="header" id="header">
    <div class="header_toggle"> 
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="header-toggle"></i> 
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="form-outline">
          <input id="search-input" type="search" id="form1" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button id="search-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    <div class="header_img"> 
        <img src="img/profile-holder.png" alt=""> 
    </div>
</header>
<div class="l-navbar" id="nav-bar">
    <nav class="nav">
        <div> 
            <a href="#" class="nav_logo"> 
                <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Logo"> 
                <img src="img/brand-white.png" alt="Logo"> 
            </a>
            <div class="nav_list"> 
                <a href="#" class="nav_link active"> 
                    <i class='bx bx-grid-alt nav_icon'></i> 
                    <span class="nav_name">Menu 1</span> 
                </a> 
                <a href="#" class="nav_link"> 
                    <i class='bx bx-grid-alt nav_icon'></i> 
                    <span class="nav_name">Menu 2</span> 
                </a> 
                <a href="#" class="nav_link"> 
                    <i class='bx bx-grid-alt nav_icon'></i> 
                    <span class="nav_name">Menu 3</span> 
                </a> 
            </div>
        </div> 
        <a href="#" class="nav_link"> <i class='bx bx-log-out nav_icon'></i> <span class="nav_name">Sign Out</span> </a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you add the event listeners to your buttons once they are loaded. You cant add them to something that doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: How would one do that? I've tried changing 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) 

to 

window.addEventListener("load", function(event)

but without success.

Comment: Correct because those will fire before the `load` function is done. But fortunately the [load function](https://api.jquery.com/load/) has a callback you can use. Like `$("#header").load("header.html", function() { /* append button events here */}); `